# Issue when downloading a file from a folder in sharepoint document library in OFfice 365 using Microsoft Graph

Tags: sharepoint-online

I was able to get Drive object for my IT folder under my xxx.sharepoint.com teamsite in office 365

```
        var drives = await graphClient.Sites["xxx.sharepoint.com"].Drives.Request().GetAsync();

        //// Get https://xxx.sharepoint.com/IT drive
        var driveIT = drives.CurrentPage.Where(d => d.DriveType == "documentLibrary" && d.Name == "IT").FirstOrDefault();
```

And, I was able to get the DriveItem object for a test.txt file under that IT folder

```
        var testfile = await graphClient.Sites["xxx.sharepoint.com"].Drives[driveIT.Id].Root.ItemWithPath("test.txt").Request().GetAsync();
```

However, when I try to download the content I get this error

Code: invalidRequest
Message: Provided identifier is malformed - site collection id is not valid

```
         // this cause the error
         var streamtest = await graphClient.Sites["xxx.sharepoint.com"].Drives[driveIT.Id].Root.ItemWithPath("test.txt").Content
                .Request()
                .GetAsync();

        // this also cause the same error.
        //var streamtest = await graphClient.Sites["xxx.sharepoint.com"].Drives[driveIT.Id].Items[$"{testfile.Id}"].Content
        //        .Request()
        //        .GetAsync();
```

However, I am able to upload a text file under my IT folder.

var uploadedFile1 = await graphClient.Sites["xxx.sharepoint.com"].Drives[driveIT.Id].Root.ItemWithPath("New_testupload_msgraph.txt").Content.Request().PutAsync(stream1);

And, I was able to upload and download test files to/from my onedrive

```
        var uploadedFile1 = await graphClient.Sites["xxx.sharepoint.com"].Drives[driveIT.Id].Root.ItemWithPath("New_testupload_msgraph.txt").Content.Request().PutAsync<DriveItem>(stream1);
        var dlteststream = await graphClient.Me.Drive.Items["01JZT44T6EFIIYDTEEJNHLPJGYC3A4VO2H"].Content.Request().GetAsync();
```

Can any body help with this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I tested your code in my SPO environment and i am able to reproduce this error.

[image]

[image]

I modified the code as below then it works well:

Change `...graphClient.Sites["xxx.sharepoint.com"]...` to :

```
graphClient.Sites[siteid]
```

site id is like:

> "abc.sharepoint.com,8f9xxxxxxx80e1e40d31,af1659xxxx-a12d-2a47800cc52d"

Here is my test demo, you may take a reference:

- https://github.com/kongmengfei/sharedproject/blob/master/TeamifySharePointClassicSite/TeamifySharePointClassicSite/DownloadfileGraph.cs

BR

Comment: Thanks for you advice and for you examples.
I have more questions on using ms graph client using csharp on the backend.

1. If I know the path example https://xxx.sharepoint.com/IT/subfolder1/subfolder2/file.txt
    a. Is there a way to make use of the path /IT/subfolder1/subfolder2/file.txt to get to the file? to download or to check if it exists.

2. If I know the path example https://xxx.sharepoint.com/IT/subfolder1/subfolder2/
    a. is there a way to search for a file under that folder using the path /IT/subfolder1/subfolder2/? also recursively searching files in subfolders .